# sqlalchemy use variable for column definition

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Let's say I have many models that all use the same type of column. e.g.

```
class PurchaseOrder(Model):
    unitprice = Column(Numeric(10,2))
    ...other columns

class SalesOrder(Model):
    salesprice = Column(Numeric(10,2))
    ...other columns
```

I would like to define some variable like;

```
currencyamount = Column(Numeric(10,2))
```

Then, if the definition ever changes I would only have one place to fix it. I would expect the model definition to look something like this now.

```
class PurchaseOrder(Model):
    unitprice = currencyamount
    ...other columns
```

If I try this I get an error along the lines of "Column object 'unitprice' already assigned to Table PurchaseOrder."

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object is shared around the app. It's the same reference that every class uses. Maybe you should try to use a factory method:

```
class PurchaseOrder(Model):
    unitprice = get_currency_column()
    ...other columns

get_currency_column():
    return Column(Numeric(10,2))
```

But to be frank, I would be surprised that the column definition changed that often.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! This is a bit of a strange case. Each customer will be able to modify their copy of the database to their needs, so things like currency will vary from country to country.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a function and then call it to generate that column.  Another nice thing about this is you can add args to customize the column config.

```py
def currencyamount_col():
    return Column(Numeric(10,2))

#...

class PurchaseOrder(Model):
    unitprice = currencyamount_col()
    # ...other columns
```

Here is a date column factory I use:

```py
def dt_column(default_now=True, onupdate_now=False, **override_col_kwargs):
    dt_kwargs = {
        "timezone": True
    }
    dt = DateTime(**dt_kwargs)
    col_kwargs = {}
    if default_now:
        col_kwargs['default'] = utc_now
    if onupdate_now:
        col_kwargs['onupdate'] = utc_now
    col_kwargs.update(override_col_kwargs)
    return Column(dt, **col_kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleanest way is to just create an abstract `Order` base class that contains your common attribute definition, and then subclass that for your different order types.

SQLAlchemy allows you to create a base class that will not be represented in the database via the `__abstract__` indicator. You can define common attributes on this class. Read more [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/inheritance.html?highlight=abstract#abstract-concrete-classes)

Something like this should work for you:

```
class Order(Model):
    __abstract__ = True
    unitprice = Column(Numeric(10,2))

class PurchaseOrder(Order):
    ...other columns

class SalesOrder(Order):
    ...other columns
```

The `unitprice` column will be inherited by both subclasses.